# Android: thread interruption callback

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Situation: activity performs some actions in background [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html). When activity is closed, android kills thread too.
I want to write thread stop into log. Is there any callbacks ? (overriding interrupt() and destroy() not works) Or i should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead ?

**UPD:**
Thread code

```
private class InternalReader extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final int size = mReader.getDataSize();
        final int blockSize = 10240;
        int offset = 0;
        TextFileCacher.DataBlock db = new TextFileCacher.DataBlock();
        db.data = new char[blockSize];
        int read = mReader.readString(offset, db.data, -1);
        mListener.onRenderStarted();
        mListener.onRenderReady();
        while (read > 0){
            db.size = read;
            mCacher.processData(db);
            offset+=read;
            mListener.onProgress(offset/size);
            read = mReader.readString(offset, db.data, -1);
        }
        mListener.onRenderReady();
    }
}
```

AsyncTask code

```
private class InternalReader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        final int size = mReader.getDataSize();
        final int blockSize = 10240;
        int offset = 0;
        TextFileCacher.DataBlock db = new TextFileCacher.DataBlock();
        db.data = new char[blockSize];
        int read = mReader.readString(offset, db.data, -1);
        mListener.onRenderStarted();
        mListener.onRenderReady();
        while (read > 0){
            db.size = read;
            mCacher.processData(db);
            offset+=read;
            mListener.onProgress(offset/size);
            read = mReader.readString(offset, db.data, -1);
        }
        mListener.onRenderReady();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Initialisation

```
(new InternalReader()).start();
```

and

```
(new InternalReader()).execute();
```

Comment: Using Java Threads in Android can be pretty cumbersome. Using AsyncTask is much more elegant and easier to manage.

Comment: AsyncTask reduced performance significantly. The same code works about 4-5 times slower.

Comment: Can you post the code here? AsyncTask shouldn't be making that much of a difference... Show us your AsyncTask as well as the place where you're initializing and executing it...

Comment: Please add the code as part of your question. Also, give the entire code of your asynctask. Are you doing the above in doInBackground(), etc, etc. Also give the code snippet in your activity where you're actually initializing the asynctask

Comment: You aren't using both, right? And how are you detecting when the asyntask/thread finishes?

Comment: Iim detecting thread finish in debugger. Surely, i've tested performance separately without eclipse debugger.

Comment: Ah.. What you have to do is to override the onPostExecute() method of your AsyncTask.. You can pass it a reference to the activity during initialization. In the onPostExecute, call the function of the Activity you want executed after doInBackground() finishes.

doInBackground() will run just as quickly as the Thread. The problem is that you haven't specified what you want it to do after it finishes executing.

Comment: Well... Moving actions with mListener to onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() didn't help. Perhaps because of some work with object in main thread. I'll try to refactor it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17018/discussion-between-vinay-s-shenoy-and-styanton)